# update a textfield when clicking on a checkbox that lies in a different panel in Wicket

Tags: checkbox, wicket, textfield

How can i update a text field that is on a panel when a checkbox on a different panel is updated?

see the image

[image]

What I am trying to do is this:

```
 AjaxCheckBox checkbox= new AjaxCheckBox("checkbox") {
        @Override
        protected void onUpdate(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
            boolean selected = getModelObject();
            if(selected){
              TextField textField = panel.getTextField();
              textField.setModelObject(obj);
              textField.add(new AttributeModifier("readonly", true, 
new Model("readonly")));

            }

        }
    };
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the second panel (that contains the checkbox) you can add an abstract method `onUpdateCheckbox(AjaxRequestTarget target)` that must be implemented by the first panel (that contains the text field).

The `onUpdate(...)` method of your `AjaxCheckBox` only has to call this abstract method.

On implementation of the `onUpdateCheckbox(...)` at the first panel you can manipulate the textfield and add it to the target object.

Comment: Just to clarify this for others like me: "abstract" here doesn't mean quite the keyword `abstract` (which would necessitate also the class being declared abstract), but just a method without any code in it. Took myself quite a while to get over that.